# Increase/decrease textfield value with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, textfield

I'm having trouble in doing a javascript that will do the following:

Increase/decrease number inside textbox when image clicked.
setting a limit for that textbox (not below zero, not above x)

please know i have many text boxes in the same page, so how can this issue be fixed?

[image: Image for illustration]

Comment: are you using any kind of library?

Comment: i tried jquery but i was looking for more simpler approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) set ids for each and every image and input field.  You will need to set name attributes for each input field though (so your server code can tell them apart - but not for JS).

If the "add" section for each row looks like:

```
<div>
  <img src='minus.png' onclick="increment(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);" />
  <input type='text' name='product_1010101011' />
  <img src='plus.png' onclick="decrement(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);" />
</div>
```

use this javascript:

```
function increment(myInput) {
  // use Mike Samuel's code here
  myInput.value = (+myInput.value + 1) || 0;
}
function decrement(myInput) {
  // use Mike Samuel's code here
  myInput.value = (myInput.value - 1) || 0;
}
```

Comment: answer i was looking for. highly appreciated!

Comment: To put limits on it, use `Math.max(0, ...)`, so `function decrement(myInput) { myInput.value = Math.max(0, (myInput.value - 1) || 0); }`.  cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think this should get you going:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" id="minus" value="-" 
    onClick="textb.value = (textb.value-1)">
    <input type="text" id="textb" name="name" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="+" 
    onClick="textb.value = (+textb.value+1)">
</form>
```

Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DHBrZ/3/)

Comment: I could give you a hand but not right now. I'll be back in an hour!

Answer (score 0):

To increment

```
myInput.value = (+myInput.value + 1) || 0;
```

To decrement

```
myInput.value = (myInput.value - 1) || 0;
```

The `|| 0` will reset any value that doesn't parse as an integer to a default value, 0.